# How to read /manipulate input in ADA?

Tags: ada

Reading from standard input, I want to be able to insert a few sets of integers like so and do some math on every 2 integers.

I.E:

**"Hello enter some numbers to get their sum":**

1 9

2 10 [enter]

**OUTPUT:**

1 + 9 = 10.

2 + 10 = 12.

I have been successful with only the user being able to enter only 2 integers as I just do

```
get(numOne);
get(numTwo);
```

and then something like:

```
 answer := numOne + numTwo;
 put_line(answer'img);
```

But I am new to ADA and don't know how I can scan through all four of the integers I used in my example and only sum the first two then the second two, and if there is more then keep summing them up by two's. Essentially the program would first scan through all the user input and do math on every two integers and keep concatenating them to a result string that we can print at the end. I know how to do it, I am just new to the language and don't how to put it in code. Please ask if you need more info. All help is appreciated.

Comment: You mean you want a loop?  Ada does have some of those.  Check out the [reference manual](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-5-5.html).

Comment: You don't understand the question, I want to eliminate the variables in the get () function so that the user can input any even amount of integers not a fixed amount and the program can add every two ints and store the result to one long string that it can print at the end.

Comment: No, we don’t understand the question. Perhaps you could post some actual code in the form of a program that at least compiles, tell us what the input is supposed to be (your example is on two lines but only the second has [Enter] after it - ?) and the corresponding output (is it supposed to print the two values that were summed?), and explain why you can’t just read the input a pair at a time, in a loop, and print the result as you go. Of course you could append the result to an unbounded string, using Ada.Text_IO.Unbounded_IO, and output that at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Just put a loop around your existing logic. - And notice that Ada has nice "infinite" loops. :-)